# Freezing in cursor moveToFirst()

Tags: java, android, cursor, sqlite

API 10, Android 2.3.3

I have the code

```
 Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from linhas as l where    exists"+ 
                "(select * from linhas_ruas_ida as l1, linhas_ruas_ida as l2,ruas as r1,ruas as r2 where l1.id_linha = l2.id_linha and l1.id_rua = r1._id and l2.id_rua = r2._id and r1.nome = '"+rua1+"' and r2.nome = \""+rua2+"\" and l.codigo = l1.id_linha and l1.posicao <= l2.posicao)"+
                "or exists (select * from linhas_ruas_volta as l1, linhas_ruas_volta as l2,ruas as r1,ruas as r2 where l1.id_linha = l2.id_linha and l1.id_rua = r1._id and l2.id_rua = r2._id and r1.nome = \""+rua1+"\" and r2.nome = \""+rua2+"\" and l.codigo = l1.id_linha and l1.posicao <= l2.posicao)"+
            "or exists (select * from linhas_ruas_ida as l1, linhas_ruas_volta as l2,ruas as r1,ruas as r2 where l1.id_linha = l2.id_linha and l1.id_rua = r1._id and l2.id_rua = r2._id and r1.nome = \""+rua1+"\" and r2.nome = \""+rua2+"\" and l.codigo = l1.id_linha)",null);  

c.moveToFirst();
```

So, my application freezes at the line c.moveToFirst(); [I can see in Debug mode]

if I change the SQL, for example

```
("select * from linhas as l where 1")
```

works fine!!!

P.S

```
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
```

[image: EXPLAIN SQL]

Comment: Could it be, it just needs time to get the output for your statement?

Should be a bigger calculation?

Comment: Hum... But I waited a lot, and nothing happened

Comment: How fast does this query execute in the `sqlite3` command-line tool? What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)?